Any way to add a Marker or a Pin on PDF files in Flutter using syncfusion_flutter_pdf
I use https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf
Any way to add a Marker or a Pin on PDF files with using onTap dx dy position?
I want to place marker or a customizable marker that opens up the current status screen of the marker on PDF files in a Flutter application. Need save markers and show when again pdf opened edit existing markers delete move and more

We do not have support for drawing SVG images in PDF documents. However, you can insert image formats like PNG and JPEG into PDF documents using the Flutter PDF library. Please refer to the UG documentation for further details:
https://help.syncfusion.com/document-processing/pdf/pdf-library/flutter/working-with-images
